# I can not add class by using e.preventDefault() method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, href, addeventlistener

I made a menu bar with HTML and CSS. I would link to add a specific class and will be worked href by using JS wherever I click, but I click any menu Item a href is not working.

**My HTML code is here.**

```
<div class="main-header">
      <h2><a href="index.html"> Javascript All projects </a></h2>
    </div>
    <div id="main-content">
      <div class="menu-bar-all-project">
        <ul>
          <li class="single-menu-class">
            <a href="index.html"> 1. Stopwatch </a>
          </li>
          <li class="single-menu-class">
            <a href="2_watch.html"> 2. Watch </a>
          </li>
          <li class="single-menu-class">
            <a href="3_countdown.html"> 3. Countdown </a>
          </li>
          <li class="single-menu-class">
            <a href="4_accordion.html"> 4. Accordion </a>
          </li>
          <li class="single-menu-class">
            <a href="5_popup.html"> 5. Popup </a>
          </li>
          <li class="single-menu-class">
            <a href="6_calculator.html"> 6. Calculator </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

My Javascript code is here.

```
const mwMenuItem = document.querySelectorAll(".single-menu-class");
for (let i = 0; i < mwMenuItem.length; i++) {
  mwMenuItem[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    for (let j = 0; j < mwMenuItem.length; j++) {
      if (i == j) {
        mwMenuItem[j].classList.toggle("mw-menu-active");
      } else {
        mwMenuItem[j].classList.remove("mw-menu-active");
      }
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

Thank you in advance.

I tried in Google an Yotube. However I did not get any expected result.
I belive, someone will help me to fix it.

Comment: When a new page is loaded all javascript variables and html state is cleared. You have to add this script to every subpage and check if the url matches

Comment: What js code I wrote, it has already been called every single page by calling before `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const mwMenuItem = document.querySelectorAll(".single-menu-class");
for (let i = 0; i < mwMenuItem.length; i++) {
 mwMenuItem[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const oldActive = document.queryselector("li.single-menu-class.mw-menu- 
   active");
  if(oldActive) oldActive.classList.remove("mw-menu-active");
  e.currentTarget.classList.add("mw-menu-active");
 });
}
```